# Alternativa a session_destroy(), sin borrar variables

Tags: php, seguridad, sesiones

estoy trabajando con sesiones en php, y tengo una duda rápida de responder, pero a mi no me queda claro por la documentación oficial de PHP.

Lo que quiero hacer es que después de iniciar una sesión ( session_start() ), me la cierre, pero sin destruir la información de las variables.

Hay alguna función adecuada para esto, o tendría que refrescar obligatoriamente el navegador.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que lo que estás buscado es [session_write_close()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-write-close.php),que escribe al información de sesión y la finaliza, así no hay que esperar a que finalice el script, que sería cuando se cierra por defecto la sesión.

> Las sesiones basadas en ficheros (lo predeterminado en PHP) bloquean
>   el fichero de sesión una vez que una sesión se abre vía
>   session_start() o implícitamente vía session.auto_start. Mientras esté
>   bloqueado, ningún otro script puede acceder al mismo fichero de sesión
>   hasta que haya sido cerrado al terminar de ejecutarse el primer
>   script, o llamando a session_write_close().
>
> Esto suele provocar problemas en aquellos sitios Web que realizan
>   muchas peticiones AJAX y tienen solicitudes mútliples ejécutandose a
>   la vez. La manera más fácil de lidiar con esto es llamando a
>   session_write_close() tan pronto como se haya realizado un cambio
>   requeirdo a la sesión, preferiblemente antes de finalizar el script.
>   Alternativamente, se podría utilizar una sesión diferente en segundo
>   plano que admita concurrencia.

Fuente: http://php.net/manual/es/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: La solución es perfecta, y es justo la descripción que buscaba, Gracias :)